# Resolving 'cannot find package' error with vendor in go 1.7

Tags: go

I have a project structure which looks like below:-

```
session-service
    _libs   //Contains all the external dependencies
    api
    constants
    exceptions
    idgen
    jsonDecoder
    log
    model
    monitor
    persistence
    redis
    routes
    src/bddtest/servicetest
    util
```

Content of `_libs` looks like below:-

```
github.com 
golang.org 
    x
        net
gopkg.in
```

My `Makefile` looks like below:-

```
.PHONY: deploy

LOGLEVEL ?= 1
CONFIGFILE ?= 2
GOFLAGS ?= $(GOFLAGS:)

PWD = $(shell pwd)
export GOPATH = $(shell echo $$GOPATH):$(PWD)/_libs:$(PWD)
export GOBIN = $(PWD)/bin
export GOROOT = $(shell echo $$GOROOT)

deploy: clean build install 

build:
    @rm -rf pkg/ 2>/dev/null
    @rm -rf _libs/pkg/ 2>/dev/null
    @go build $(GOFLAGS) ./...

install:
    @go install ./...

clean:
    @go clean $(GOFLAGS) -i ./...


## EOF
```

Everything is working fine. Now I am thinking of moving to `vendor`. So I renamed my `_libs` to `vendor` and modified my `Makefile` like below:-

```
export GOPATH = $(shell echo $$GOPATH):$(PWD)
```

But after this I started getting the following error:-

```
vendor/golang.org/x/net/html/charset/charset.go:20:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/text/encoding" in any of:
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/vendor/golang.org/x/text/encoding (vendor tree)
        /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/text/encoding (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/golang.org/x/text/encoding (from $GOPATH)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/src/golang.org/x/text/encoding
    vendor/golang.org/x/net/html/charset/charset.go:21:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap" in any of:
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/vendor/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap (vendor tree)
        /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap (from $GOPATH)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/src/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap
    vendor/golang.org/x/net/html/charset/charset.go:22:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/text/encoding/htmlindex" in any of:
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/vendor/golang.org/x/text/encoding/htmlindex (vendor tree)
        /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/text/encoding/htmlindex (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/golang.org/x/text/encoding/htmlindex (from $GOPATH)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/src/golang.org/x/text/encoding/htmlindex
    vendor/golang.org/x/net/html/charset/charset.go:23:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/text/transform" in any of:
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/vendor/golang.org/x/text/transform (vendor tree)
        /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/text/transform (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/golang.org/x/text/transform (from $GOPATH)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/src/golang.org/x/text/transform
    vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/h2i/h2i.go:38:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal" in any of:
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal (vendor tree)
        /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal (from $GOPATH)
        /Users/debraj/golang/src/b/m/session-service/src/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal
```

Environment:-

- go version go1.7.3 darwin/amd64
- Mac OS X 10.11.6

Can someone let me know why I am getting the above errors with `vendor` but everything works fine with `_libs`?

**UPDATE**

In my local the newlines in the output of `$(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)` was causing some problem. So to resolve this I had to modify the `jimb` 's solution a bit. I introduced a variable in `Makefile` `PKG = $(shell go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/ | tr "\n" " ")` and then used that variable in `go install` & `go build` like `@go build $(GOFLAGS) $(PKG)`

Comment: I think you have packages in `vendor/` that don't have all their dependencies, but you weren't building them before. Don't use `./...`, install just the packages you want to build.

Comment: But everything was working fine when I had all the dependencies under `_lib`. Also are you saying that I shouldn't be using `go install ./...`?

Comment: The reason you prefixed `_lib` with a leading underscore is to make it ignored by the go tools (unless you just happened to do that by sheer luck), which is why it worked before. No, you shouldn't be using `go install ./...` in this case. Install just the specific main packages you want built.

Comment: Yeah you are right I added `_` in front of `lib` for go tools to ignore it.  I have added `_lib` in `$GOPATH` in the `Makefile` so that the dependencies are found during the build. If I get you correctly then since I am doing `go install ./...` so it is building `vendor` also that is why it is failing but in case of `_libs`    these were not getting build. Since I have added all dependencies under `vendor` can you let me know if is there a way I can build all packages and exclude `vendor` from getting build?

Comment: How many main packages do you have? Can you just list the package names? If that's unreasonable for some reason, you could do something like `go install $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)`

Comment: I have updated the question with all the package names. I don't want to add the package names in `go install` because overtime this will increase and each time a new package is created then this also has to be added in `Makefile`. I modified my `Makefile` as you suggested - `@go build $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)`. But on doing `make build`  this is giving me the error - `can't load package: package bitbucket.org/myntra/session-service: no buildable Go source files in /Users/debraj/golang/src/bitbucket.org/myntra/session-service
make: *** [build] Error 1`

Comment: How many "main" packages do you have? Running `go install` installs all dependencies too, so you don't need to run it on _every_ possible package.  I don't know what is causing that error without seeing the contents of that directory. Look at the list of packages you're installing; look at their contents; make sure you only have what you need vendored, and you don't have a nested vendor directories (a tool like `govendor` will help with that).

Comment: The newlines in the output of `$(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)` was causing the problem. So to resolve this I introduced a variable in `Makefile` `PKG = $(shell go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/ | tr  "\n" " ")` and then used that variable in `go install` & `go build` like `@go build $(GOFLAGS) $(PKG)`.

Comment: @JimB - Can you post all your comments as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to trim that though -- maybe it has to do with the Makefile which I didn't try (I usually have the Makefile call a shell script for more detailed builds though)

Comment: Without `tr` all packages are coming in different lines as they are separated by newline causing problem with `go install`

Comment: I've also used `$$(go list ./... | grep -v vendor/)` (in a Makefile), not sure if that makes a difference . Never seen the newline problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_libs` directory starts with `_`, and is ignored by the `go` tool. When you move the packages to `vendor/`, the `./...` wildcard now includes all packages in the vendor directory.

You should explicitly list the package you want to install, rather than rely on the `./...` wildcard. If you still want the wildcard behavior, you can use `go list ./...` and filter any package containing a `vendor/` directory in their path. Depending on your specific needs, this could be as simple as:

```
go install $(go list ./... | grep -v vendor/)
```